# Find biggest pattern in a given matrix

Tags: algorithm

I am new to the world of algorithmic problems and this one has been giving me hard time. I have been trying to solve this for a few days and at this point I feel kinda lost. I have a solution but it is way too slow for huge inputs, so I am currently trying to find somewhat more efficient way.

The goal is to find the biggest SIZE (output is the number) of pattern in the shape of H in a given matrix that consists of dots ('.'), circles ('o') and X letters ('X'). The matrix has m rows and n columns. 2 ≤ m, n ≤ 2000.

The pattern must be composed of dots('.') and may contain only one circle ('o') at most. The pattern must not contain any 'X' letters. The pattern is composed of left, right and middle pillar and the middle pillar cannot touch the the top or the bottom of left or  right pillar.

e.g.:

```
X...
.o..
X...
..o.
```

In the matrix above the biggest size of H is 9.

This patterns are allowed:

```
. .     .       .                                              
. o     .       .
. .     .........
. .     .       .    . .
...     .       .    ...
. .     .       .    . .
```

but these variants are not allowed:

```
.    o 
.    .
.    .
.    .
......            

.....o 
.    .
.    .
.    .
.    .
```

The ways I have been thinking about this:

My naive solution looked like this:

```
 for (int leftCol = 0; leftCol < n - 2; leftCol ++ ){
 for (int rightCol = n-1; rightCol > leftCol + 1; rightCol--){
  //searchForBiggestHLeftO() with 'o' in the "left pillar" of H between rightCol and leftCol
  //searchForBiggestHRightO() with 'o' in the "right pillar" of H between rightCol and leftCol
  //searchForBiggestHMiddleO() with 'o' in the "middle pillar" of H between rightCol and leftCol
  //searchForBiggestH() without any 'o' between rightCol and leftCol

 }  
}
```

The solution above (even though it worked) became useless for matrices of bigger size (hundreds x hundreds or even thousands x thousands). Since that I have been trying to find other more efficient ways to compute the size of H.

The most similar problem I found on the internet was the solution on how to find the biggest pattern of shape '+' composed of '1' in a binary matrix.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-size-of-the-largest-formed-by-all-ones-in-a-binary-matrix/

But unfortunately I have not been able to apply the solving algorithms in any functioning way. The fact that the patter may contain one circle 'o' became my stumbling point.

I believe there is some handy way of how to view this problem that I have failed to see. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you favor any language for this - eg. Python, JS, etc?  Do you have the source of the problem to include here?

Comment: @DanielHao I'd prefer C++ but Python is fine as well. As for the source of the problem: It is one of programming problems that served as implementation tests for final exams of one of my subjects at my school. So I am just going through test from previous years. The assignment is in foreign language but I have access to testing input data and can send them to you (probably by email?).

Comment: I'll take a look once I've more sample data/inputs.  At work now. Probably in Python.

Comment: If u want some input data I'll be happy to provide them, but I dont know if I can send direct message with attachment to you here.

Comment: You can post inputs on some other site, and provide a link to it here.

Comment: This should work: https://www.uschovna.cz/zasilka/PVVN6NW8ZA26AS3M-AK2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In O(m n) time, we can compute for each matrix entry

- How many consecutive dots are above (below, left of, right of) it
- How many consecutive entries above (below, left of, right of) it are neither X nor a second circle

by scanning each column upward and downward and each row leftward and rightward. This leads to an O(m n²)-time algorithm by iterating over rows, iterating over pairs of entries in the row (i.e., guessing the degree-3 vertices of the H), doing constant work on the computations above.

Actually I think we can do better. Sketchy details here, but guess the row (i.e., iterate over rows), sort the columns by how high they can reach with and without including a circle, and insert them in decreasing order of height into an online data structure with operations

- Insert(i, depth)
- Query(i′, depth′): returns the maximum value of |i − i′| + min(depth, depth′) for previously inserted (i, depth),

implemented using an appropriately augmented segment tree.